# Android to AWS: How to

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, google-play

I got a violation notice from Google Play (per the picture below). How would I pass the data securely or what cryptographic methods should I use in my Android code and in AWS cloud to enforce the data security while sending data from Android app to AWS cloud

https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/personal-sensitive/

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the most straightforward methods to encoding your data for storage and transmission would be to use a AES CB encryption using a key-salt pair.

Do not store any unencrypted passwords/personal data in a database. Do the encryption server side then check for validation [for username - password combinations].

below is a link that I have used before to implement this encryption.
https://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2013/02/07/aes-cb-encryption-in-android-using-key-and-salt/#.Wl7w-bPhk_s

[keep in mind since its a bit old some methods may have depreciated and may need to be changed]